# spring security CORS filter allows requests without the "Origin" header

Tags: java, spring, security, cors

I'm trying to add the Spring Security CORS filter to a REST API.

I've successfully configured the CORS filter and if I add to my requests an invalid "Origin" header, the request is correctly rejected with a 403 - forbidden http status.

The problem is that if I send a request without the "Origin" header, the CORS filter authorises it and the response code is an http 200.

1. Is this the way the CORS mechanism is designed?
2. Is it correct what I'm trying to achieve, i.e. reject all the requests sent without the "Origin" header?
3. Is there a way to tell Spring Security CORS filter to reject that kind of requests?

Comment: CORS is a browser-side restriction.  Requests without `Origin:` typically come from non-browser clients, which can send whatever they want.  And they can easily send any origin.  What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: ok thank you for pointing me in the right direction, but does this mean that there is no point in adding a CORS filter to a REST API?

Comment: Only if you want to allow access from cross-domain Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SLaks described in his comments to the answer, the CORS headers are automatically added and filled by a browser client and the CORS filtering only makes sense in such a scenario.

When a request comes from a "non-browser" client, any content can be passed in the `Origin:` header, making it pointless to force the clients to add the header, and the server to reject a request without it.

Consequently the answers to the questions are:

1. yes
2. no, there's no point in doing this
3. no